# cURL with PHP, possible to determine the IP address cURL will use?

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to determine programmatically what IP address cURL is using when connecting to a remote server? I have a shared server that I am using cURL on, and I need to send the IP address as part of the request.

The server that I am talking to requires an authentication string that combines the connection IP address and a rotating passcode (eg my $code = SHA1($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . $passcode) gets compared on their end with SHA1($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $passcode)). This worked fine when the outgoing connection from cURL was using the same IP as is stored in $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], however the IP address used by cURL is now different and rotating periodically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to get your public IP before you call:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://whatismyip.org/');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
$myIp = curl_exec($ch);
```

However:

- If your public IP sometimes changes between cURL sessions, there is nothing to say that it wont change between the above session and the next one for which you actually need this data.
- It relies on `whatismyip.org` (or similar service) actually being running.

Comment: +1, though I would not have given it without the very important caveat, that there is no guarantee that the IP will be the same from one call to another if there is a pool.  Unknown whether multiple cURL sessions within a single call will be from the same IP even.

Comment: For now, this is the solution I am using, but with a service on my end, rather than whatismyip to determine the IP address faster and with no access restrictions. Unfortunately, with 3,000 connections an hour, this is not the most efficient solution for me, so I'm still looking.

Answer (score 3):

You can force the IP that curl uses, as opposed to detecting it.

Use the `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` option for [`curl_setopt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) - set it to the IP you wish to use.

If you are using a server, such as a cloudserver, with an IP pool - then it is advisable to select the interface to use, if it is important to detect that on the other side, for security reasons.

Personally, I have had to use the feature for card payment data transfers via cURL, when the IP is restricted.

Comment: +1 for best solution, but may not be possible on shared hosting.

Comment: @DaveRandom: Most shared hosting platforms have at least a primary IP for the hosting server that can be bound to - though it is not always permitted as you say to alter.

Comment: The other point about this that I have just thought of is that if they have multiple IP addresses bound to a single NIC, choosing an interface may not guarantee a particular IP address, even if you pass a specific IP. cURL only uses the interface reference (like `eth0`), and if you pass an IP/hostname it uses that to get an interface reference. Actually assigning a source IP to the packet is the responsibility of the NIC driver and there is nothing that can be done to control it (at least, not through PHP).

Comment: @DaveRandom: Aye, quite right in principle.  I have found that it tends to work when I specify the IP, but as you say, routing past the interface is at a different level.  `iptables` possibly could help, but no use unless the OP has a dedicated server.

Comment: Using this method did have limited success, about 75% of the outgoing connections actually used the IP address I passed to CURLOPT_INTERFACE, but the remaining 25% used one of the other four IP addresses assigned to that interface.

Comment: @Wige: Hmm, well, as DaveRandom notes - if there are multiple IPs assigned to the *interface*, then it can decide to use another.  Network routing is intended to be beyond the scope of userland applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is a web site called whatismyip.com.  They have a publically available API that you can use as long as you don't exceed their limit (which is something like five requests per hour??).  Won't hurt to give it a shot, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that curl is always running from the same server, even if it has multiple NICs it shouldn't matter if you tell curl which IP to use.

I would use DaveRandom's trick of getting what IP you are currently using, then set it for the next call using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX");
```

Assuming the two calls are close enough, there is a very high chance that IP will still be bound to an interface and by setting it you are telling curl to use that one, instead of whichever one the load balancer may want to use.